# FFMPEG - Streaming GoPro4 to RSTP

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp, gopro

Greeting!
I'm planning to capture a realtime streaming video from GoPro4 and load it into TouchDesigner in order to use this footage in a projection mapping project.

So far I was able to play GoPro4 stream using ffplay doing as follows:
1. Host GoPro4 WiFi hotspot.
2. Connect a laptop WiFi to GoPro4's hotspot.
3. Restart GoPro stream service by opening 'http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&c1=restart' in s browser.
4. Run ffplay command in order to open ffplay stream video window: 'ffplay -an -fflags nobuffer -f:v mpegts -probesize 8192 rtp://10.5.5.9:8554'

The next step I opt to make it to re-stream this signal into RTSP protocol so TouchDesigner could receive this signal.

And here is my question - how to re-stream this input to RTSP?

Answer (score 0):

You could stream the GoPro feed to localhost and then load it on touchdesigner. I don't have any experience with touchdesigner but if it's like OBS then you just need to add the localhost rtsp URI as an input. See how I did it to stream to Facebook and YouTube; https://github.com/KonradIT/gopro-py-api/blob/5581dc4e2225cacd10a15b978534efdb0df89830/examples/streaming/README.md

Proof of it working in OBS:  https://twitter.com/konrad_it/status/852425858753146881?s=09